# Dynamics Remote Assist via another unity App (application its closing)

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, remote-assistance

Im facing the issue that When I push the bottom to call to the user via Dynamics Remote assist via LauncherUriAsync method my application is closing.

I want to know if its possible to run the call and continue with my application running together.

Thanks
Rafael Souza

Answer (score 2):

For `LaunchUriAsync`, It is not possible to launch another app and continue with your app running together since `LaunchUriAsync` will do a non-modal launching and that will suspend the calling application, more information please see:[App model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/app-model#protocols).
And it is recommended to try to do it modal though to see if it does meet your needs: [LaunchUriForResultsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher?view=winrt-19041#Windows_System_Launcher_LaunchUriForResultsAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_Windows_System_LauncherOptions_Windows_Foundation_Collections_ValueSet_)